# Get value of an generated hidden field

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, pickadate

I'm using the Datepicker from angular2-materialize, it is based on Pickadate, and I need to send a different value to the server than what is displayed to the user. Classical case.
For this, Pickadate provides an option : formatSubmit which creates an hidden input which holds that internal value. I'm even able to have this input having the same name that my main input (with hiddenName parameter).

```
<input type="date" id="dateOfEvent" name="dateOfEvent" 
       [(ngModel)]="claimFile.dateOfEvent" class="datepicker" 
       materialize="pickadate" [materializeParams]="[{format: 'd mmmm yyyy', formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd', hiddenName: true}]" required />
```

That generates an hidden input below the component :

```
<input type="hidden" name="dateOfEvent" value="2016-10-20">
```

The problem is that hidden input is not binded to my ng2 model. 
How can I do that ? If it isn't possible, how can I get a way to access the value of my hidden input ? 
thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" #hidden name="dateOfEvent" value="2016-10-20">
```

```
@ViewChild('hidden') hidden:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.hidden.nativeElement.value);
}
```

If it is not possible to add a template variable to the hidden element

```
consturctor(private elRef:ElementRef){}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.elRef.querySelector('input[type="hidden"]').value);
}
```

Comment: I get `TS2339: Property 'querySelector' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>'`

Comment: @acarlstein `this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(...)` might work.